# My display is blurry 16.04

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

Randomly after I restarted my computer the other day my screen was blurry, so I just rebooted to try and fix it and it worked. Now it's blurry again but reboots won't fix it! I'm using a single monitor atm.

So far I've tried checking my resolution, it's on 1920x1080 like it's supposed to be. I've also checked my drivers, purging nvidia and reinstalling it.

If you need any more info tell me.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you may have hardware issues.  It could be your monitor, video cable, or graphics card.

1. Check to see if is just Ubuntu. Upon boot up the monitor display is clear for system splash screen and bios?  Try a live media like Ubuntu install disk or Knoppix. If it's still fuzzy, then it's not software.
2. Try plugging in the computer to another monitor or your TV and see if the problem migrates with your computer. If it's still fuzzy, then it's not your monitor.
3. Try a new video cable. If it's clear, throw out the old cable.
4. Use an alternate video source to test the monitor.

Comment: During boot up it's fine. Only once I get to my login screen does it become blurry. Also I restarted it again today and it's fine.